# Chemical detection of cell division

Tags: chemical-biology

So I have been working on a project for a while, and there is one mechanism that I need a little bit of advice about.

The project is chemical-biology based, so don't be deterred :)

Theoretically, by this point in the experiment:

I put cells (let's say lymphatic or endometrial) into stasis, through means of lyopreservation, and now, I have brought them out of stasis, through exposure to a sucrose (trehalose)-based medium.

Now I am attempting to **chemically detect mitotic growth** within the cells, how can I do this?

This is where the chemistry comes in: My first thought was to use a **chromatic indicator** that would fluoresce or irradiate in response to mitotic acceleration, but I have not yet found a suitable chemical. In research, I found that a similar experiment had been done in bacteria, and the chemical **dimyristoylphosphatidylcholine** (1,2-Dimyristoyl-sn-glycero-3-phosphocholine) had been used. Would this work in mammalian cells? Another idea was to use a chemical that detects the unnatural growth from the **spindle fiber and centriole** point of view, reacting when the centrioles entered the phase to replicate. I have been unable to find any chemicals that make use of the replication of centrioles, or the spindle fibers, so I need ideas.

To summarize: Does anybody know of any **biochromatic indicators** that react through **detection of rapid, mammalian, mitotic growth**? Not necessarily cancerous and uninhibited, but rapid meaning 'a speed of mitosis that is faster than the norm.' Preferrably, the indicator would be able to stay in **stasis** for extended periods of time.

If such an indicator is not available (or you do not believe so) then does there exist a **biochromatic indicator** that reacts in the presence of **any** sort of **cell division?**

Is there a way to **chemically detect cell division**?

I am welcome to all ideas.

[image]

([figure source / chemspider.com](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.4573168.html))

Comment: I have a feeling this would do better in Biology.SE with the biochemistry tag.

Comment: Possibly, and I might post it there, but since I was specifically asking about the existence of a chemical, I thought I would try Chem first.